# my code does not safe different pages in my db

Tags: laravel, pagination, backend, laravel-5.7

js:

```
$('#sortable').sortable({


        stop: function(event, ui) {

            saveContentOrder();
        }
    });
    function saveContentOrder()
    {

        const idsInOrder = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");


        var data = {
            idsInOrder:idsInOrder
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "/xxx/yyy/zzz",
            data: data
        }).done( function() {

        }).fail(function() {

        });

    }
```

index.blade.php:

```
<tbody  id="sortable" >
                    @foreach ($references as $index => $reference)

                        <tr id="reference_id_{{$reference->id}}">
                                <td width="65%">
                                    <a href="{{ route('admin.reference.edit', $reference->id ) }}"><b>{{ $reference->title }}</b>
                                    </a><br>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @if(!count($reference->images))<span style="color:#ff0000;font-weight:700;">0</span>@else{{ count($reference->images) }}@endif
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ $reference->priority }}
```

my webroute:

```
Route::post('/xxx/yyy/zzz', 'AdminReferenceController@reorder');
```

my Controller:

```
public function reorder(Request $request)
    {
        $order = $request->get('idsInOrder',[]);
        if (is_array($order))
        {
            foreach($order as $position => $idName)
            {
                $id = str_replace("reference_id_","",$idName);
                $gesamt = Reference::all()->count();
                $c = \App\Reference::find($id);
                if($c)
                {
                    $c->priority = $gesamt-$position;
                    $c->save();
                }
            }
        }
```

when i am on my first page it saves the position and priority change that i drag and drop.but when i go to the second page for example and drag and drop the order it gives the same priority as in page 1. which means it displays thinks first that should be 20th or 30th. i basically want it to be on the right order all the time. i have a show 10, show 30, and show 100. when i for example get to the show 30 and i have no pages since i dont have so many entries right now it works without issues. but as soon as i go to show 10 and got 3 pages the priority gets mixed up. how can i fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this is js File:

$('#sortable').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        saveContentOrder();
    }
});
function saveContentOrder()
{ 
  const idsInOrder = $(this).sortable("serialize");
  var data = {
        idsInOrder:idsInOrder
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "/xxx/yyy/zzz",
        data: data
    }).done( function() {

    }).fail(function() {

    });
}


this is controller file

public function reorder(Request $oRequest)
{  
   //$oRequest->idsInOrder get all orders positiion ids.affter drag 
    data like,
//orders[]=6&orders[]=5&orders[]=3&orders[]=4&orders[]=2&orders[]=1
  parse_str($oRequest->idsInOrder);
    $nCount = 1;
    foreach($orders as $order)
    {
      // update database order
        $nCount++;
    }
    return Response::json(['success' => true]);
}
```